# Code not working as expected in C

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, strcat

I was working on a program in C to count the number of spaces in a sentence. But I haven't managed to get it to work properly. If I enter  something like *Hello world 1234 how are you* the output I'm getting is 3 when the output expected is 5.
My code is :

```
//Program to count number of words in a given Sentence
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char sent[100];
    char sentence[] = {' ', '\0'};
    printf("\nEnter a sentence :\n");
    gets(sent);
    strcat(sentence, sent);
    int l = strlen(sentence), i = 0, count = 0, countCh = 0;
    printf("%d", l);
    char ch, ch1;
    for (i = 0; i < (l-1); i++)
    {
        ch = sentence[i];
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            ch1 = sentence[i+1];
            if (((ch1 >= 'A') && (ch1 <= 'Z'))||((ch1 >= 'a') && (ch1 <= 'z')))
                count++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNo of words is : %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I used the same logic in Java and it worked fine. Could someone explain whats going wrong?

Comment: never use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: `strcat(sentence, sent);` Can't it. because `sentence` is no extra space. E.g `char sentence[102] = {' ', '\0'};`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I didnt get you

Comment: @SouvikSaha try replace `char sentence[] = {' ', '\0'};` with `char sentence[102] = {' ', '\0'};` : (sizeof( /*your */ sentence) is 2)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you so much! That did the trick!

Comment: `strcat` does not create an area of the new string unlike java. see [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY okay thanks! I assumed that 'strcat' adds the total memory locations of both sent and sentence. Guess I'm not used to string memory allocations of C. Thanks again! This was bumming me out since yesterday!

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is with the definition of `sentence`. When you leave out the array dimension and initialize it, the size of the array will be determined by the length of the initializer.

Quoting the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, **and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;**

That is, the program will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This way, `sentence` has certainly way less memory than it it supposed to hold. Moreover, `strcat()` is not at all *required* there.

The correct way to do it will be

- Define `sentence` with a proper dimention, like `char sentence[MAXSIZE] =  {0};`, where `MAXSIZE` will be a MACRO having the size of your choice.
- use `fgets()` to read the user input.
- use [`isspace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) (from `ctype.h`) in a loop to check for presence of space in the input string.

Comment: @SouvikSaha what? You said you want to count the number of spaces, now you are saying that's not enough, what's your goal anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
       if (((ch1 >= 'A') && (ch1 <= 'Z'))||((ch1 >= 'a') && (ch1 <= 'z')))
            count++;
```

probably should be

```
       if (ch1 != ' ')
            count++;
```

As now " 12345" would not be counted as word.

Also `count` counts the spaces, so the word count is one more: hence 3 instead of 5.

Your `sentence` seems to have had the intention of counting the terminatin NUL.

If you want to count real words containing letters, use a bool state whether current and prior state of being in a letter differ.

As mentioned overflow is possible with your code.